# C# SerialPort write behavior different debug vs runtime

Tags: c#, arduino

Working on a Windows Form App to control a servo motor with an Arduino (via serial com over USB). Code on the Arduino works, confirmed with Arduino IDE built-in serial monitor. The windows form and the Arduino are exchanging character strings. Problem is different data is sent to Arduino when I step through using Visual Studio debugger vice letting the program run at race pace.

Idea is: a character string is sent to the Arduino, which processes and acts on it. Right now, I just want to confirm the two are talking correctly so Arduino only reads a three-character command received from PC and sends the third character back (e.g. PC sends "01d" and Arduino returns "d"). Again, this works fine in the terminal application. Does not work with my C# form.

Where I get lost: If I put a breakpoint anywhere before the actual SerialPort.WriteLine call and step through the code from there it performs perfectly. If the code executes at race pace up to and past the SerialPort.WriteLine call, it sends the wrong string: instead of "01d" it sends "??01d". This is based on the having the Arduino return the entire command string it received from the PC (for troubleshooting).

I have tried many things: building the command string in different ways, using a StringBuilder object, using a char array (vice string type), using SerialPort.Write, putting sleep statements in different places ahead of the serial write (thinking the delay from debugging has something to do with it). All exhibit the same problemm, so I need some help looking elsewhere.

Code below (I'm learning, so **constructive** feedback is always appreciated):

SerialCOM class [this is an excerpt, to keep length marginally reasonable]

```
  class SerialCom
     {
        public void WriteCOM_Line(string txData)
        {
           try
              {
              serialPort.WriteLine(txData);
              }
           catch (ArgumentNullException e)
              {
              _ = MessageBox.Show("TxData data field is NULL.\r\n" + e.Message, "Error");
              }
           catch (InvalidOperationException e)
              {
              _ = MessageBox.Show("The specified port is not open.\r\n" + e.Message, "Error");
              }
           catch (TimeoutException e)
              {
              _ = MessageBox.Show("Serial write did not complete before the time-out period ended.\r\n" + e.Message, "Error");
              }
        }
     }
```

ServoController Class [contains methods/properties to control the servo]

```
   class ServoController
      {
      public string CmdString;
      private SerialCom serialCom;

      public ServoController(SerialCom serialCom)
         {
         this.serialCom = serialCom;
         CmdString = null;
         }

      public void BuildCommand(Command cmd, char ret, char data1)
         {
         /* Builds the command string that will be sent to the Arduino, based on input parameters. This method should be called prior to calling SendCommand */
         if (cmd == Command.Cmd_Handshake || cmd == Command.Cmd_SendServoState)
            {
            //CmdString = Convert.ToString((int)cmd) + ret + data1; originally coded this which also doesn't work
            CmdString = "01d"; //hard coded for troubleshooting
            }
         }

      public void SendCommand()
         {
         /* Transmits the command to the Arduino. Assumes the BuildCommand method has been called prior to calling this method */

         if (CmdString != null)
            {
            serialCom.WriteCOM_Line(CmdString);
            }
         }
      }
```

Code from the Form class, specifically the Connect Button's click event handler

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
      {
      private SerialPort serialPort;
      private SerialCom serialCOM;
      private ServoController servoController;

      public Form1()
         {
         InitializeComponent();
         serialPort = new SerialPort();
         serialCOM = new SerialCom(serialPort);  
         }

      private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
         /* When the button is pressed, if the serial port is not already open, try opening. */
         if (!CheckSerialParams(COMDropdownList, BAUDDropDown))
            {
            return;
            }

         string resp;

         if (serialCOM.OpenPort())
            {
            servoController = new ServoController(serialCOM);
            servoController.BuildCommand(Command.Cmd_Handshake, '1', (char)100);
            servoController.SendCommand();

            resp = servoController.GetResponse();

            if (resp[0] == (char)100) //hardcoded for troubleshooting
               {
               StatusTextBox.Text += "Handshake passed on " + serialPort.PortName + "\r\n";
               }
            else
               {
               StatusTextBox.Text += "Handshake failed on " + serialPort.PortName + "\r\n";
               StatusTextBox.Text += "Response received from MCU: " + resp + "\r\n";
               }
            }
         else
            _ = MessageBox.Show("The selected port could not be opened.", "Error");
         }
      }
```

Arduino Code:

Header file:

```
#pragma once

/* Serial Comm Parameters */
#define SERIAL_BAUD 9600

/* PC Controller Commands */
#define PC_HANDSHAKE '0'
#define SEND_NUM_SERVOS '1'
#define SEND_SERVO_STATE '2'
#define SET_SERVO_STATE '3'

#define CMD_BFR_LENGTH 8 /* Size of command string buffer */
#define MAX_CMD_BYTES 5 /* Number of bytes in the longest command string */
#define CMD_TERMINATOR '\n' /* Command string termination character */

/* Command String Fields */
#define CMD_FIELD cmdBuffer[0] /* Stores the Command Number */
#define RETURN_FIELD cmdBuffer[1] /* Stores the flag indicating if a response is expected */
#define DATA1_FIELD cmdBuffer[2]  /* Stores either the subject servo number or handshake return value */
#define DATA2_FIELD cmdBuffer[3] /* Stores commanded direction (only used for SET_SERVO_STATE command) */

/* Global Variables */
const char CmdStrings[][17] = /* Array that holds string values for names of commands */
   {
"PC_HANDSHAKE", /* 0 */
"SEND_NUM_SERVOS", /* 1 */
"SEND_SERVO_STATE", /* 2 */
"SET_SERVO_STATE", /* 3 */
   };

char cmdBuffer[CMD_BFR_LENGTH]; /* Array that holds each byte of the command string sent from PC */

/* Servo Parameters */
const size_t servoPins[] = /* Array that holds the pin number for each Servo connected */
   {
2,
3,
   };

const byte numServos = sizeof(servoPins) / sizeof(servoPins[0]); /* Number of servos connected to the board */

Servo* servoArry = new Servo[numServos]; /* Array of Servo objects, one for each pin represented in servoPins[] */

/* Macros */
#define SAFE_SET(a, b, c, d) (b < c ? a=d : a=-1) /* If b < c, set a to d. Else set a to -1 */
```

Source file:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include "PCServoController.h"

void setup()  
   {
   /* Setup all the servo motors */
   for (int i; i < numServos; i++)
      {
      servoArry[i].attach(servoPins[i]);
      }
   /* Setup Serial for communication with computer */
   Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUD);
   } /* END setup */

void loop() 
   {
   /* Wait for data to arrive */
   while (Serial.available() < 1)
      {}

   Serial.readBytesUntil(CMD_TERMINATOR, cmdBuffer, (size_t)CMD_BFR_LENGTH);

   switch (CMD_FIELD)
      {
      case PC_HANDSHAKE:
         /* Call handshake routine */
         SerialHandshake();
         break;

      case SEND_NUM_SERVOS:
         TxNumServos();
         break;

      case SEND_SERVO_STATE:
         Serial.print("Command Received was: ");
         Serial.println(CmdStrings[2]);
         //TxServoState();
         break;

      case SET_SERVO_STATE:
         Serial.print("Command Received was: ");
         Serial.println(CmdStrings[3]);
         // SetServoState();
         break;

      default:
         /* Command not recognized */
         Serial.print(cmdBuffer);
         Serial.print("\n");
         /* Call TxErrorMsg() */
         break;
      }
   } /* END loop */


   void SerialHandshake()
      {
      /* Function returns the value indicated in the Data field of the command string received from the PC Controller. This value is used by the controller to verify communication with this board. Print value type is BYTE */

      Serial.println(DATA1_FIELD);

      } /* END SerialHandshake */

   void TxNumServos()
      {
      /* Function returns the number of servos currently connected to the board. The number is a calculated value based on the length of the servoPins array. Print value type is BYTE */

      Serial.println(numServos);

      } /* END TxNumServos */

   void TxServoState()
      {
      /* Function returns the state (pointing direction) of the servo indicated in the Data field of command string received from the PC Controller. If servo number indicated is greater than the number of servos connected, prints the error value (-1). Print value type is INT */

      int state = 0;

      SAFE_SET(state, cmdBuffer[2], numServos, servoArry[cmdBuffer[2]].read());

      Serial.println(state, DEC);

      } /* END TxServoState */

   void SetServoState()
      {
      /* Function sets the servo indicated in the first data field of the command string to the direction (angle) indicated in the second data field of the command string. Assumes the direction commanded is between 0 and 180 degrees. If servo number indicated is greater than the number of servos connected, returns without setting any direction */

      int state = 90;

      SAFE_SET(state, cmdBuffer[2], numServos, (int)(cmdBuffer[3]));

      if (state < 0)
         return;
      else
         servoArry[cmdBuffer[2]].write(state);

      } /* END SetServoState */
```

Comment: What's with all the discards `_`?

Comment: Where is the Arduino part either the troubleshooting routine or the real program?